# how to use Fact() function to print the facts to the screen, it goes wrong

Tags: function, types, clips

I embed CLIPS into C Language. 
I want to get the facts and print them to the screen
when use Facts() in the main.c 
it returns "Logical name ��[Í�� was not recognized by any routers"
the code is

```
main()
{
    char *Facts;
    char str[10];
    InitializeEnvironment();
    Load("my.clp");
    Reset();
    Facts(Facts,NULL,-1,-1,-1);
    Run(-1L);

}
```

I don't known how to solve it

Thanks for any idea and code examples.

Comment: It looks like your initialisation sequence might be wrong - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265951/clips-c-code-that-read-a-value-from-the-fact-answer-is-value-if-it-is-known-fi) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a logical name in the call to Facts:

```
Facts("stdout",NULL,-1,-1,-1);
```

You're currently passing in an uninitialized variable.